Transient Analysis on Variable Resistance
The solution of the following question is given by applying KVL across the loop and then proceeding accordingly.
But why isn't the general equation of transient analysis applicable here? The equation I am referring to is :
x(t) = x(∞) + [x(0+) - x(∞)]e-t/Τ
where x is any parameter of the circuit in question and T is the time constant. Why can't I apply this equation to the current I(t) to get the answer?

LeperMessiah - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/etc. name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. (See more rules in [tour] & [help].)

The time t is limited to [0, T], higher it can't be, so forget "infinity", or change variable.
The resistance become than "negative".
Made with microcap v12

See comparison with exponential (curve in red).
The value of the current ( @t=T/2 = 1.5 ) is equal to 0.25 A.
